# Javascript: Loop prints only last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using below loop to print data in javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++){
     var getbills = result.data;
     var html = "<tr>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].customername+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].customerphone+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].tablename+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].sale_date+" "+getbills[i].sale_time+"</td>";
     html+= "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='"+getbills[i].id+"' 
     class='btn btn-primary' 
     onclick='payforthependingorder("+getbills[i].id+")'>View</a><br /><a 
     href='"+baseURL+"Sale/deletesales/"+getbills[i].id+"' class='btn btn- 
     danger'>Delete</a></td>";
     html+= "</tr>";
     $("#billonholdtable").html(html);
  }
```

it has following values when i see in network tab

[image]
but only last one is printed in table, please helo me with this. Thanks

Comment: `$(ele).html()` overwrites the current data in that element. You re-create `html` each time on your iteration and overwrite on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `$("#billonholdtable").html(html);` in your code, which makes every iteration re-generate a new html instead of appending it.

How about this?

```
var content= '';
for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++){
     var getbills = result.data;
     var html = "<tr>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].customername+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].customerphone+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].tablename+"</td>";
     html+= "<td>"+getbills[i].sale_date+" "+getbills[i].sale_time+"</td>";
     html+= "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='"+getbills[i].id+"' 
     class='btn btn-primary' 
     onclick='payforthependingorder("+getbills[i].id+")'>View</a><br /><a 
     href='"+baseURL+"Sale/deletesales/"+getbills[i].id+"' class='btn btn- 
     danger'>Delete</a></td>";
     html+= "</tr>";
     content += html;
}
$("#billonholdtable").html(content);
```

Comment: Perfect Answer ! Thanks a lot Noob

Answer (score 4):

Take 
`$("#billonholdtable").html(html);` out of loop or

use

```
$("#billonholdtable").append(html);
```

Comment: This table is shown in a modal window on a button click  if i use append on every click event it appends 3 more entries,

Comment: You have to make HTML blank of billonholdtable before loop execution start

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a variable html is out of the loop.
var html='';
within the loop you  have  to define as mentioned below.
     html+= "values";